# ¿Cómo uno y sumo valores de distintas tablas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente necesito mostrar ciertos valores de un script de departamentos
[image: ejemplo]
Por el momento he hecho esto

```
SELECT 
EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO", 
COMUNA.NOMBRE_COMUNA AS "COMUNA",
TO_CHAR(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_DVRUN as "RUN ADMINISTRADOR", -- v 
INITCAP(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO) "NOMBRE ADMINISTRADOR", 
COUNT(DEPARTAMENTO.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS"
FROM 
COMUNA
JOIN 
EDIFICIO    
ON 
COMUNA.ID_COMUNA = EDIFICIO.ID_COMUNA
JOIN 
ADMINISTRADOR
ON 
ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN = EDIFICIO.ADM_NUMRUN   
JOIN
DEPARTAMENTO
ON
DEPARTAMENTO.ID_EDIFICIO= EDIFICIO.ID_EDIFICIO
GROUP BY 
EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO, COMUNA.NOMBRE_COMUNA, TO_CHAR(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_DVRUN, INITCAP(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO)
ORDER BY 
"COMUNA","NOMBRE EDIFICIO";
```

Y me ejecuta estos valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a la hora de agregar los DEPARTAMENTOS que NO han CANCELADO los gastos comunes me complico demasiado... Estaba intentando algo así

```
SELECT 
EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO", 
COMUNA.NOMBRE_COMUNA AS "COMUNA",
TO_CHAR(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_DVRUN as "RUN ADMINISTRADOR", -- v 
INITCAP(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO) "NOMBRE ADMINISTRADOR", 
COUNT(DEPARTAMENTO.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS",
SUM(CASE WHEN d.ID_ESTADO_PAGO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS NO CANCELAN GC"
FROM 
COMUNA
JOIN 
GASTO_COMUN_PRUEBAESTPAGO d
ON  
d.ID_ESTADO_PAGO = d.ID_EDIFICIO
JOIN
EDIFICIO    
ON 
COMUNA.ID_COMUNA = EDIFICIO.ID_COMUNA
JOIN 
ADMINISTRADOR
ON 
ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN = EDIFICIO.ADM_NUMRUN   
JOIN
DEPARTAMENTO
ON
DEPARTAMENTO.ID_EDIFICIO= EDIFICIO.ID_EDIFICIO
GROUP BY 
EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO, COMUNA.NOMBRE_COMUNA,      TO_CHAR(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_DVRUN,     INITCAP(ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_PNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_SNOMBRE || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_PATERNO || ' ' || ADMINISTRADOR.ADM_APELLIDO_MATERNO)
ORDER BY 
"COMUNA","NOMBRE EDIFICIO";
```

PERO ese código no me ejecuta nada :( Estaba intentando SUMar todos los valores que ID_ESTADO_PAGO sea igual a 2 (osea PENDIENTE O ATRASADO)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el modelo png del sistema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se me viene a la mente utilizar operador MINUS o quizás el operador NOT IN con una subquery pero sinceramente no puedo llevarlo código.
En resumen,debo agregar a mis filas los departamentos totales por zona que aun no han pagado sus gastos comunes :/ pude lograr todo el resto menos eso.

Comment: Esto parece Oracle, no SQL Server.

Comment: Tienes un error en la siguiente parte del código: `GASTO_COMUN_PRUEBAESTPAGO d
ON  
d.ID_ESTADO_PAGO = d.ID_EDIFICIO`